# Daemon thread not working as expected

Tags: java, multithreading

```
package main.components;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainSnoozerx implements Runnable, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static int min = 0;
    static Thread mnz = new Thread(new MainSnoozerx());
    private long convertedToMiliSec = 0l;
    private Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            do{
            System.out.println("Enter minutes to snooze..");
            min = scn.nextInt();
            }while(min<0);

        convertedToMiliSec = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(min);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(convertedToMiliSec);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Alarm Now!!!");
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mnz.setDaemon(true);
        mnz.start();
    }

}
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong/missing?
My program just terminates when I run it without printing the syso even once.
I expect the code to run endlessly being a daemon thread and the user just sets the mins once and the snooze goes on forever...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You fired the thread without ever tell Java that you want the work done back. You need to add a `mnz.join()` after your start ;)

With that fix, your thread run one time for sure. If you decide to put all your run() code inside of a while loop and change your loop, you got the behaviour that you want.

Like this

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            while (min == 0) {
                System.out.println("Enter minutes to snooze..");
                min = scn.nextInt();
            }

            convertedToMiliSec = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(min);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(convertedToMiliSec);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("Alarm Now!!!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mnz.setDaemon(true);
    mnz.start();
    mnz.join();
}
```

Comment: That worked just fine :) ... what does Thread.join(); actually do and does its context stay only with Daemon threads?

Comment: Join is a way to say 'ok give me the result'. Calling join can block your main thread if the thread is still working. (In this case, it is and will always be since the thread code is inside of an infinite loop). Your setDaemon is not relevant anymore btw.

Comment: So my thread now just works like a normal thread which we never end as it is in a loop. Then how can I make use of daemon thread to achieve this(Why use a daemon thread ever is what I mean ?)

Comment: A daemon thread is useful if you want to do something else and have a service in the background. (Like sorting a list or saving each 10 min). If your program only do a daemon job, it's not a daemon and that may be why Java don't let you run a daemon thread without a main tread doing job.

Answer (score 4):

You've got it the wrong way around, the JVM will keep running while there is at least one **non-daemon** thread alive. The `main` thread is not a daemon thread and if no other non-daemon threads are created before the main thread exits the JVM will exit.

If you want the JVM to keep running, remove the `setDaemon` call